# Adding .pfx file to existing .pkcs8 file

Tags: openssl, certificate, pfx, cer

I've been thrown in at the deep end here and most things are assumptions, so please correct me where I go wrong.

We currently have an application that references a .pkcs8 file, which I assume is a certificate chain. Recently we've been provided with a new .pfx file. In order for the application to work, we would need this new .pfx file to be incorperated/chained to the existing .pkcs8 file.

What is the best way of doing this? I've been playing around with openssl and converting the .pfx file into all sorts but don't really want to overwrite or replace the existing .pkcs8 file as I don't know what else may be in the file.

These were the initial errors from our application that led me here:

```
Loading CA Certificates from directory certs/CA :
total CA certificate count = 6
Loading certificate chain from PKCS7 :
Loading private key from certs/xxxxxkey.pkcs8, pwd = ********

STATE: Receiving the server's certificate
STATE: Sending alert because: Certificate unknown
```

TIA

Answer (score 0):

PKCS#8 standard is defined by [RFC5208](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5208). It specifies a format for private keys or encrypted private keys. PKCS #12 defines an archive file format for storing many cryptography objects as a single file.

I suggest you extract private key information from .pfx.
You can use openssl or (my preference using [xca](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xca/)). If you decide to use xca then create new database file in xca. Then import pfx file in **Certificates** tab. Then go to **Private Kyes** tab where you should find private key that was in .pfx file you imported. Click export and check **Export as PKCS#8** and save to .pkcs8 file.